LostFocus on outer div triggers on inner div
I have:
<div @onfocusout="@((e) => HidedicList(e))">
   <input for="toggleVendors" class="form-control label-toggle" placeholder="Vendor Information" @onchange="selectedValue" @onfocus="@((e) => ShowdicList(e))" />
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggleVendors" class="hidden-checkbox" >
    <div id="diclist" class="@showhide">
        <ul>
            @foreach (var item in (Dictionary<int,string>)this.selectListItems.Items)
            {
                <li><input type="checkbox" id="@item.Key" @onchange="@((e) => CheckboxChanged(e, @item.Key))" value="@item.Value" /> @item.Value</li>
            }
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

I am trying to 'roll my own' dropdown (there are valid reasons why I cant use existing methods such as a datalist with options) everything seems to work accept when focus is lost on the whole div, i want to close the inner div. So I click into my input box and my inner div shows my items. As soon as I start attempting to select one of my checkboxes in the list, the onfocusout event triggers on my outer div. If I move the event to my inner div, it doesn't trigger the event straight away, but it still triggers after I've made a selection of a checkbox in the list.

First of all, don't know why but the arrow function doesn't work for me in that case. Try to do <div onfocusout="HidedicList('unique_id_of_the_element')"...
Secondly, from what I know onfocusout won't work with div, there is a hack to define tabIndex to make it work so: <div tabIndex='1' onfocusout='Hid.....
You can also define the click event on the HTML body, and then check on which element click was fired and if it was your dropdown then close it.
